# Repeatbehavior does not make animation end properly

Tags: xaml, animation, win-universal-app

I have a coloranimation in a UWP application to animate the background of a TextBox:

```
        animation = new ColorAnimation();
        animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600);
        animation.From = Colors.White;
        animation.To = Color.FromArgb(255, 40, 40, 40);
        animation.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(2);

        flashStoryBoard = new Storyboard();
        flashStoryBoard.Children.Add(animation);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, MyBox);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)");
```

When I run the animation above, the animation ends in the TextBox having a white background color instead of the expected default (which is the dark 40, 40 ,40 color..). When I remove the repeatbehavior the animation runs just fine but of course only once. There are no easing functions applied. When I set the fillbehavior to stop, I get a flickering effect at the end of the animation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run the animation above, the animation ends in the TextBox having a white background color instead of the expected default (which is the dark 40, 40 ,40 color..).

I'm not able to reproduce this problem, by my side it ends with the color "FF404040". Maybe you can create a new blank project and try your posted code again. Or you can share your sample with us.

> When I set the fillbehavior to stop, I get a flickering effect at the end of the animation.

I think you are trying to make the `TextBox`'s background changed from white to dark gray twice when the `TextBox` is loaded, but when set `RepeatBehavior` equals or over two times, it will  flicker one more time very quickly in the end.

I found a workaround for this scenario, it makes the animation ending with the color "FF404040" and will not flicker in the end:

```cs
Storyboard flashStoryBoard = new Storyboard();
ColorAnimation animation = new ColorAnimation();
animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600);
animation.To = Colors.White;
animation.From = Color.FromArgb(255, 40, 40, 40);
animation.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(2);
animation.AutoReverse = true;
flashStoryBoard.Children.Add(animation);
Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, MyBox);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)");
flashStoryBoard.Begin();
```

As you can see in my code, I swap the `animation.To` and the `animation.From`, and set the `AutoReverse` property to true. Since your animation's `Duration` is only 0.6s, I think this method will not effect the user experience and can solve the flickering problem.

Comment: Hi Grace, your solution does not create the same animation I made. However, I found a fix: when I set the repeatbehavior to 1.97 instead of 2, the animation seems to work properly. This does seem like a bug in the system... Is there any place to properly post this as feedback?

Comment: @WJM, Really? Good to know! I didn't even think about such a solution, thanks for sharing. I already report this as a bug days ago, but you can also report it through the Windows Feedback tool, you can find this tool by searching the installed app in your windows 10 app, or you can try MSDN forums.